# python "signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter" in flask with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, subprocess

I am current working on a flask web server,
and want to use a function to finish the workflow of child processes when trigger ctrl+c from the parent process.

`main.py` is the parent process, starting by `python3 main.py` directly.

And the child processes(`app.py`) is **started with the subprocess.popen(...)** after the `main.py`.

```py
# main.py
def get_flask_env():
    flask_env = os.environ.copy()
    if "FLASK_APP" not in flask_env:
        flask_env["FLASK_APP"] = "./server/app.py"
    if "FLASK_ENV" not in flask_env:
        flask_env["FLASK_ENV"] = "development"
    return flask_env

def start_flask():
    flask_env = get_flask_env()
    command = []
    # the command to start app.py, would be: flask run --host 0.0.0.
    command.append(python_command)
    command.append("-m")
    command.append("flask")
    command.append("run")
    command.append("--host")
    command.append("0.0.0.0")
    monitor = subprocess.Popen(command, env=flask_env)
```

when I start the flask server(`app.py`), I catch the error in the flask server to handle clear:

```py
def handle_exit(*args):
    # clear multiprocessing here
    pass
```

then set the `signal` in `app.py`:

```py
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,  handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  handle_exit)
```

I had success use this in the parent process(`main.py`), but had problem if I use signal in child processes, the problem:

`signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter`

So how to use the signal properly subprocess?

**Edited:**

For now, I use the `subprocess.run(...)` in the `main.py` to kill all the multiprocessing with linux command: `pkill`, but this is not a cross-platform way and might terminate the process without properly wait it finish.

Comment: Well you can use a `atexit` hook in your main thread, and then call `monitor.terminate() and monitor.wait() ` which will send the kill signal to subprocess

Comment: I never know `atexit`, and it might be an acceptable answer. But it is a old project and it is hard to test it with atexit now, but still Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. What I was thinking is something like this.

```
import atexit
import os
import subprocess


def teardown(process_handle):
    process_handle.terminate() #kill the sub process clean
    process_handle.wait()# wait for graceful exit.


def get_flask_env():
    flask_env = os.environ.copy()
    if "FLASK_APP" not in flask_env:
        flask_env["FLASK_APP"] = "./server/app.py"
    if "FLASK_ENV" not in flask_env:
        flask_env["FLASK_ENV"] = "development"
    return flask_env


def start_flask():
    flask_env = get_flask_env()
    command = []
    # the command to start app.py, would be: flask run --host 0.0.0.
    command.append(python_command)
    command.append("-m")
    command.append("flask")
    command.append("run")
    command.append("--host")
    command.append("0.0.0.0")
    monitor = subprocess.Popen(command, env=flask_env)
    atexit.register(teardown, monitor) #register to execute at exit
```